# CefSharp detect webm video end

Tags: c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I have a WPF C# application using cefsharp v79.1.360.
The app is happily playing a single local webm file inside the browser.

Now I would like to pass a string of local file names to the app and play them sequentially. Thus when one webm finishes playing the next one in sequence will start. Nothing else is contained in the page, just the webm.

My first thought was to detect when the current webm finishes and then load the next file. I am not seeing any events being thrown or handlers that can do this for me.
I am using the FrameLoadEnd handler for other purposes but it only fires when the webm has finished loading, not when it is done playing.

Anyone know if detecting the ending of a webm video is possible?

My other thought is to load each webm into a stream and play the entire batch.
For user experience purposes I think it would be better to play each one individually, in sequence.

Thanks

Comment: Create a html page with a video element that controls playing your videos, there's the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/ended_event you can easily create a playlist and cycle through the videos.

Comment: CefSharp does not give you access to the DOM. Looking at playing inside a html page that calls a .Net method when the video ends. Then I can try to adjust the video source via a javascript call from CefSharp

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#JSEvent  You can pass a javascript function reference and get a `IJavascriptCallback` to then execute when your method is complete. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/c27524f456ad2a530d9aab614db917d8bdf03cae/CefSharp.Example/JavascriptBinding/BoundObject.cs#L116

Comment: You can use `DevTools` for debugging if you have any problems see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#javascript-debugging

Answer (score 0):

Decided the best way to solve the problem was to create an html page that would accept a delimited string of video locations. It handles cycling through the list, playing each one individually. All it had to do was change the src of the video tag when the onended event fired and when the loadPlaylist function below is called.

The C# app passed the playlist to the html via a javascript call:

```
Browser.FrameLoadEnd += (sender, args) =>
{
     //Wait for the Main Frame to finish loading
     if (args.Frame.IsMain)
     {
         var playlist = navigationContext.Parameters[NavigationParameterKeys.WebAddress].ToString();
         args.Frame.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("loadPlaylist('" + playlist +"');");
      }
};
```